# Оставить только уникальные элементы в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

У меня есть list, как я могу получить на выход новый без "2"?

```
some_list=[1, 2, 3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12897374/4928642

Comment: Те методы я видел, на выходе мы получаем уникальные значения. А мне надо ещё удалить "2", то есть повторяющийся элемент в list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [51]: from collections import Counter

In [52]: c = Counter(some_list)

In [53]: res = [x for x in some_list if c[x] == 1]

In [54]: res
Out[54]: [1, 3]
```

в функциональном стиле:

```
In [57]: res = list(filter(lambda x: c[x] == 1, some_list))

In [58]: res
Out[58]: [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Я нашаманил: https://ideone.com/8ZGZX0

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2]
s = set()
print(list([(s.add(x) or x) for x in lst if x not in s]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Без использования сторонних библиотек и если неважен порядок элементов:

```py
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2]
new_list = [e for e in set(some_list) if some_list.count(e) == 1]
print(new_list) #[1, 3]
```

Comment: В сет можно и не конвертировать, тогда даже порядок сохранится: ``e for e in some_list if some_list.count(e) == 1``.

Comment: @Эникейщик А если `some_list = [1, 2, 3] + [2] * 100500`? Конвертация в `set` дабы избежать лишних итераций по ненужным элементам.

Comment: Да, согласен. .